# Win32Exception when authenticating as server using certificate Ephemeral key

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate2

I'm trying to established an HTTPS connexion to a web server through SSL stream using google chrome (last version), I'm generating my certificate using `CreateSelfSignedCertificate(string commonName)`  and when I call `https://localhost/` it allways raises a `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException : A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception -> Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate`

I'm using an Ephemeral Key and I don't want to store the certificate.

here's my code:

```
...
ServerCertificate = CreateSelfSignedCertificate("localhost");
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
SslStream s  = new SslStream(_stream, false, ValidateServerCertificate);
s.AuthenticateAsServer(ServerCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
_stream = s;
...

...
public bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}

public static X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificate(string commonName)
{
    X500DistinguishedName subjectName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN={commonName}");

    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest(subjectName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));

        X509Certificate2 certificate = certificateRequest.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1));

        byte[] pfxData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);

        return new X509Certificate2(pfxData, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

- had to use SAN because google chrome requires SAN and never uses CNN fallback.

Comment: Why are  you exporting the PFX and reimporting it? Just use your existing `X509Certificate2`. Side note: remove the line `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =` it's unnecessary and cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: but then if I just return the selfsigned certificate created withotu exporting it, I get a ```System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'No credentials available in the security package'``` ...

Comment: Yes I see it's been mentioned as an open bug if you do it like that. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23749 Try passing `null` instead of `""` as the password in the contructor. And add also `certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(new OidCollection { Oid.FromFirendlyName("Server Authentication") }, false));`

Comment: i tried passing ```null``` instead of ```""``` in ```return new X509Certificate2(pfxData, null, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);``` but sadly I get an ```CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'X509Certificate2.X509Certificate2(byte[], string, X509KeyStorageFlags)' and 'X509Certificate2.X509Certificate2(byte[], SecureString, X509KeyStorageFlags)'```, Also for```X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension``` I get an ```CS7036 None of the arguments specified matches the required parameter 'group' of 'Oid.FromFriendlyName(string, OidGroup)'``` after ```KeyUsageExtension```

Comment: `(string) null` for the first. And for the second: `certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(new OidCollection { Oid.FromFriendlyName("Server Authentication", OidGroup.EnhancedKeyUsage) }, false));`

Comment: okay, I do need some epxplaination though, what is ```FromFriendlyName()``` supose to do and what is the ```Server athentication``` when there's none needed ? young student tryign to learn and understand. (haven't ran it yet, I allways try to understand before doing so);

Comment: If you want to authenticate as a server then the certificate should have the `Server Authentication` key usage. The function is just to get the OID for `Server Authentication`, but you can put it in as a string if you want `1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1`. Did that work now?

Comment: well, I tried with the basic string ```"1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"``` but it did throw that : ```System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The OID value is invalid.```. ```certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(new OidCollection { Oid.FromFriendlyName("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1", OidGroup.EnhancedKeyUsage) }, false));```

Comment: No you don't need the function `FromFriendlyName` then, just `certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));`

Comment: well I'm back at the initial error doign so : ```System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 'Call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.'``` -> ```Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate```. this is such a complex behavior to workaround, i'm speechless... i don't usualy stay stuck that long, it's been almost 1 week already

Comment: Which version of Windows are the server and client? Exact build numbers please.

Comment: well, I don't exactly know where to find that information is the project solution in visual studio, but maybe it is that : ```ASP.NET and WebTools - 17.4.326.54890 and Microsoft Windows 11 Professional Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621``` ? the client is google chrome last version, and the server is running on a visual studio project version 17.4.4. -> .NET 4.8.09032

Comment: @Charlieface bumping again, I don't know if you found something that could help me so far.

Comment: No I haven't, what happens if you try it with a hard-coded password?

Comment: I've updated my post , I did manage to get through but still having trouble

Comment: You should store the certificate in some static cache, then look it up as needed. Post your answer as part of the answer, not in the question. You are free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ANSWER

#### Authenticating using an Ephemeral key is not possible on Windows, because the underlying OS component that provides TLS/SSL doesn’t work with ephemeral keys.

**see github issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23749)**

Also:

```
byte[] pfxData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, (string)null);
                return new X509Certificate2(pfxData, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);
```

is basically the same as just `return certificate`.

**The reason that people do the pkcs12 export and re-import is to **NOT** specify EphemeralKeySet** *(you should also not assert PersistKeySet, unless you really mean to)*.  And you likely don’t need Exportable, either.

```
byte[] pfxData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, (string)null);
                return new X509Certificate2(pfxData);
```

would work much better.

***The issue that I was having was best described by an issue that has gotten locked due to old age on the github Issue linked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23749).***

***Thanks to Barton Jeremy Barton at Microsoft for helping me on this and pointing some light on this subject.***

---

## SOLUTION

#### To work around that behaviour :

Either switch to a Linux-based Azure App Service using Azure Key Vault to manage your certificates. Azure Key Vault can securely store certificates and private keys and automatically handle renewals.

#### OR

#### You have to persist the Certificate to a particular CSP using `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet`

here is my code so far, this basically stores the self signed certificate once it has been created so your server is able to `AuthenticateAsServer()` without throwing a Win32 Exception.

Function to create the selfsigned certificate on demand *(free to tweak it as needed)*:

```
public void CreateSelfSignedCertificate()
{
    string commonName = "My Authority CA";

    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        // Create a subject name
        X500DistinguishedName subjectName = new X500DistinguishedName($"CN={commonName}");

        // Create a self-signed certificate
        CertificateRequest certificateRequest = new CertificateRequest(subjectName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        // Add a "Key Usage" extension to the certificate during its creation.
        // The "Key Usage" extension defines the purposes for which the public key of the certificate can be used.
        // X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment: The public key can be used to encrypt data, typically by encrypting a session key that is then used to encrypt the actual data.
        // X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment: The public key can be used to encrypt other keys, for example, in the TLS protocol during key exchange.
        // X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature: The public key can be used to verify digital signatures.
        // The second parameter of X509KeyUsageExtension specifies whether the extension is critical or not.
        // If it is critical (true), applications that do not understand this extension must reject the certificate.
        // If it is non-critical (false), applications that do not understand this extension can still accept the certificate.
        certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));

        // oid 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 = "Server Authentication"
        // oid 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 = "Client Authentication"
        // oid 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 = "Code Signing"
        // ...
        certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(new OidCollection { new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1") }, false));

        // Add SAN extension (fallback)
        var sanBuilder = new SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder();
        sanBuilder.AddDnsName("localhost");
        sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"));

        // Add all Machine IPv4 ou IPv6 configuration to SAN extension
        foreach (var ipAddress in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
            if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork || ipAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                sanBuilder.AddIpAddress(ipAddress);

        certificateRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(sanBuilder.Build());

        // Set the certificate date and duration
        X509Certificate2 certificate = certificateRequest.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1));

        // Export the certificat
        pfxData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);
    }
}
```

code to store the certificate to the specific CSP before authenticating only if it doesn't exist yet *(here we store it to the LocalMachine trusted certificate as Google shares those and have access to it)*

```
...

ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxData, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
bool certificateExists = false;
foreach (X509Certificate2 existingCert in store.Certificates)
{
    if (existingCert.Subject == ServerCertificate.Subject && existingCert.HasPrivateKey == ServerCertificate.HasPrivateKey && existingCert.GetCertHashString() == ServerCertificate.GetCertHashString())
    {
        certificateExists = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!certificateExists)
    store.Add(new X509Certificate2(_certificateContent));
store.Close();

...
```

I hope it helped you

***Thanks to @Charlieface for is help***

Comment: Thank you! According to this blog post,https://www.pkisolutions.com/handling-x509keystorageflags-in-applications/ we should avoid storing certificates on the host machine as they persist after the application terminates, potentially leaving sensitive information on disk. I am not sure what to do then, Is the only realy alternative to use host certificate store? 

Also there is a question about caching, if we retrieve the certificate from the store, does it need to be cached?